# Xcode: Two frameworks that needs two different c++ Standard Library

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, build-settings

I'm working on an app where I need to use two c++ based frameworks and I can't find how to configure build settings so they both build.

One of them works with C++ Standard Library libc++, the other one, with libstdc++.

Is there a way to specify a c++ library by framework? Or at least, a main c++ library and an exception for the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that C++ Standard Library is set to libstdc++ (GNU c++ standard library) in the Apple LLVM 5.0 Compiler Build Settings